# What is meant by this notation for ensemble classifier error rate

Tags: classification, ensemble-modeling, notation

The below is a picture which denotes the error of an ensemble classifier. Can someone help me understand the notation

[image]

What does it mean to have (25 and i) in brackets and what is ε^1 is it error of first classifier or the error rate raised to power i. Can someone explain this formulae.

Comment: ${25 \choose i}$ is a [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient). The whole expression is the calculation of bernoulli distribution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\varepsilon^i$ is the error rate raised to the power i. So for each value i, the formula calculates the probability of i classifiers classifying a sample incorrectly, so for i=13 we have:
$$e_{13\ wrong} = {25 \choose 13} \times \varepsilon^{13} \times {(1-\varepsilon)}^{12}$$
Assuming $\varepsilon = 35\%$, and calculating the binomial coefficient gives us:
$$e_{13\ wrong} = 5,200,300 \times 0.35^{13} \times 0.65^{12} = 0.035$$
Repeat this for $i = 14, 15, ... , 25$, then sum all the results to get the final answer.